# Apk installs but won't start only on Android 4

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-4.4-kitkat

My application works fine on Android 4, 5 and 6, when I plug devices to computer. But when I get .apk file from app/build/outputs/apk directory and install it directly, application crashes on Android 4 on start. Only on Android 4. Why? And how to fix it?

Here is my manifest file:

```
<manifest package="ru.pussy_penetrator.chgk"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".QuestionGridActivity"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".QuestionPagerActivity"/>

</application>
```

Comment: If it crashed can you capture the exception/error in Logcat and paste it?

Comment: No, when I plug in my device and start Android Studio, Logcat doen't show anything at all. I'll try to use some Logcat apps on my phone to see the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the Instant Run and Build the APK. Instant Run uses the device cache to hot swap the changes you make in the project. Also it optimizes the code to run on the platform that your testing device has.

You can also generate Signed apk for distributing across all the supported Android versions